# while mongoDB , hive integration getting error

Tags: mongodb, hadoop, hive

I am trying to integrate mongodb hive and getting this error while executing:

Query: `Select * from minute_bars;`

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.mongodb.DB.isAuthenticated()Z
at com.mongodb.hadoop.util.MongoConfigUtil.getCollection(MongoConfigUtil.java:328)
at com.mongodb.hadoop.splitter.MongoSplitterFactory.getSplitterByStats(MongoSplitterFactory.java:76)
at com.mongodb.hadoop.splitter.MongoSplitterFactory.getSplitter(MongoSplitterFactory.java:114)
at com.mongodb.hadoop.hive.input.HiveMongoInputFormat.getSplits(HiveMongoInputFormat.java:64)
at com.mongodb.hadoop.hive.input.HiveMongoInputFormat.getSplits(HiveMongoInputFormat.java:44)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FetchOperator.getRecordReader(FetchOperator.java:442)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FetchOperator.getNextRow(FetchOperator.java:588)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FetchOperator.pushRow(FetchOperator.java:561)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FetchTask.fetch(FetchTask.java:138)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.getResults(Driver.java:1621)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:267)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:199)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:410)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:783)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:677)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:616)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
```

I already imported jars as per my knowledge :

```
add jar /home/gumbi/bigdata/hadoop-2.7.2/bin/hive-serde-0.10.0.jar;
add jar /home/gumbi/bigdata/hadoop-2.7.2/bin/mongo-java-driver-3.2.2.jar;
add jar /home/gumbi/bigdata/hadoop-2.7.2/bin/mongo-hadoop-core_2.2.0-1.2.0.jar;
add jar /home/gumbi/bigdata/hadoop-2.7.2/bin/mongo-hadoop-hive_2.2.0-1.2.0.jar;
```

I tried to create a table, working fine, but not able to execute select query. 
for table creation query is given below:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE minute_bars
(
  id string,  
  userId string, 
  memberId string,firstName string 
)
STORED BY 'com.mongodb.hadoop.hive.MongoStorageHandler'WITH SERDEPROPERTIES('mongo.columns.mapping'='{"id":"_id","userId":"userId","memberId":"memberId","firstName":"firstName"}')TBLPROPERTIES('mongo.uri'='mongodb://localhost:27017/localvedantu.orgmembers');
```

Comment: You have copied the jars to the wrong directory. Copy them into `lib` directory, not bin.

Comment: Hi  Mobin Ranjbar

i tried but again i am getting same error

Comment: You have not included the version number. It is hundred percent version problem. com.mongodb.DB.isAuthenticated() was removed in mongodb-java-driver since 3.0 and was deprecated since 2.12.

Comment: Hi Mobin Ranjbar 
My mongoDB Version 3.2.8
i tried  mongo-java-driver-2.12.2.jar version
but i am getting error java.io.IOException:java.io.IOException: com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out while waiting to connect after 5 ms

Comment: and which version is suitable mongo-java-driver?

Comment: That is different error and it is related to the mongod and connection problem. I think your problem has been resolved.